# distorted image in pgm binary file manipulation

Tags: c++, image-processing, vector, binary, convolution

I'm trying to perform convolution on a `pgm` image of type `P5` (*binary*)
with the set up below:

input and output array

```
vector<vector<char>> image(rows, vector<char>(cols, '\0'));
vector<vector<char>> out(rows, vector<char>(cols, '\0'));

const int SIZE = 3;
```

Filter

```
vector<vector<int>> filter = { { 0, -1, 0 }, { -1, 5, -1 }, { 0, -1, 0 } };
```

insert binary data into image array

I'm reading PGM file like this:

```
getline(infile, type);
//getline(infile, comment);   
infile >> rows >> cols;   
getline(infile, line);
getline(infile, highest);    
//getline(infile, line);

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        infile >> image[i][j]; //infile is from filestream


outfile.open("output.pgm");

//Insert default header attributes into output pgm file.
outfile << type  << "\n" << rows << " " << cols << "\n" << maxpx << "\n";


    for (int i = SIZE / 2; i < rows - SIZE / 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = SIZE / 2; j < cols - SIZE / 2; j++)
        {
            uint8_t sum = 0;
            for (int k = -SIZE / 2; k <= SIZE / 2; k++)
            {
                for (int l = -SIZE / 2; l <= SIZE / 2; l++)
                {
                    sum += image[i+k][j+l] * filter[k + SIZE / 2][l + SIZE / 2];
                }
            }
          out[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }
```

Write binary data into out file

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        outfile << out[i][j];
```

I do not get any error when I run the code, but the image is distorted. I can clearly make out some part of the output image, but it's is not coming out complete.

Not sure if it has to do with my manipulation.

Update:

I changed `uint8_t` to char, but I still get the same error.

1. When I change `outfile << out[i][j];` to `outfile << image[i][j];` so I can get the actual image back, but looks like there could be some issues with how I'm reading the file into `image` vector. Not sure how to at this point.
   I get this image[image]

[Lena.pgm file](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/pgmb/lena.pgm)

[MCVE(Pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/yiHJ8c3R)

Comment: Please provide a Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve which can be compiled and tested if you want the best assistance.

Comment: There's also not likely to be another line after `highest` but before the data, so you may have a `getline` too many. It depends on the writer though.

Comment: That seem to get if even clearer, the image is still distorted though. Just curious, adding that extra `getline` seem to work fine for `P2` images.

Comment: If you change all your filter coefficients to `1`, and assign `out[i][j]=sum/9;` do you get a correctly blurred image?

Comment: @MarkSetchell No I don't. I still get half distorted image.

Comment: Can you share your input and output images?

Comment: If you change your coefficients to `0,0,0,  0,1,0,  0,0,0` you should get your original image.

Comment: When I implement identity filter, I do not get the original image.

Comment: At this point my guess is that there is a bug in your for loop math. I would look at the edge cases of `SIZE / 2`

Comment: Try replacing the part where you write the output file `outfile << out[i][j];` to write out the unchanged input file instead `outfile << image[i][j];`. If that doesn't work, you need to look at your image loading part. If it does work, you need to look at your filtration part.

Comment: Please share your input PGM file.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Question update.

Comment: I have solved it! I reduced the contrast on your Lena image (I used **ImageMagick** and did `convert lena.pgm -level -25% lena.pgm` and now your program can read and write it fine. Instead of varying between 0-255, your data now varies between 67-197. That means that `ifstream` is somehow interpreting low value bytes of image data (i.e. blacks) as linefeeds, or special characters. I never use `ifstream`but it seems that the `ios::binary` flag is not doing what you want somehow.

Comment: http://thesetchells.com/lena.pgm

Comment: I think you maybe have to use `infile.read(...)` rather than `>>`

Comment: Could please give a proper answer for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am no expert on C++, but I believe you cannot (or maybe should not) use the `>>` operator to read binary files.

I worked this out by noticing that your image goes wrong where there are black pixels and I believe that these null bytes are being interpreted incorrectly by `ifstream` when you don't actually want them interpreted at all. I decreased the contrast on your image so the range of the pixels was no longer 0-255 but 67-197 and it all works. So it works when there are no low values in your image.

I believe you need to change the way you read the binary image data from:

```
infile >> image[i][j];
```

to something like:

```
infile.read((char*)&image[i][j],1);
```

or maybe something using `get()`. Sorry, I cannot be more precise, as C++ is not my forte but hopefully you can now proceed further. If anyone cares to explain what I am saying in a comment - please feel free to teach me! Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure! Sorry it took me so long - I had a lot to learn myself on this one :-) Anyway, glad it works and good luck with your project!

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. You could probably go cleaner than the `.read` and C-style cast by using an `istreambuf_iterator` instead.

Comment: And yes, you are correct about `>>`. [The documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) says that when streaming in to a `short`* or an `int`* "Behaves as a `FormattedInputFunction`. After constructing and checking the sentry object, ***which may skip leading whitespace***, extracts an integer value by calling `std::num_get::get()`." *there is no overload for `char`, so it must be implicitly converting from an integer type

Answer (score -1):

Check out the documentation for [text and binary streams](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c#Binary_and_text_modes):

> A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into lines (zero or more characters plus a terminating `'\n'`). Whether the last line requires a terminating `'\n'` is implementation-defined. Characters may have to be added, altered, or deleted on input and output to conform to the conventions for representing text in the OS (in particular, C streams on Windows OS convert `\n` to `\r\n` on output, and convert `\r\n` to `\n` on input)
>
> ...
>
> A binary stream is an ordered sequence of characters that can transparently record internal data. Data read in from a binary stream always equals to the data that were earlier written out to that stream. Implementations are only allowed to append a number of null characters to the end of the stream. A wide binary stream doesn't need to end in the initial shift state.

The default format for a `std::fstream` is non-binary, that is, it treats the input and output as a text stream. You want to manipulate the raw bytes in the file, so you want to treat it as a binary stream. To specify a binary stream, use the `std::ios::binary` flag in the constructor of your `std::fstream` object.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion, that didn't seem to solve the problem.